# Is there a way to get frequencies of nominal values in R?

Tags: r, frequency

This seems to be pretty basic but I am stuck!

The nominal values are:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I import data from csv and a column looks like:

```
1 1 1 0 0 3 1 3 3
```

So, I want to calculate the frequencies of the nominal values and get something like:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 4 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The closest thing I've found is to use table but as expected it doesn't include the 0 frequencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `table` after converting your data to a `factor`:

```
nominal.vals <- 0:9
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 3)
table(factor(x, levels=nominal.vals))
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
# 2 4 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Excellent! factor seems to be the what I wanted!! Thanks a million.